# Kubernetes PODs hostname as env

Tags: api, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have suchlike problem:

```
    spec:
  hostname: kafka
  containers:
  - name: kafka
    image: registry/wurstmeister:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    restartPolicy: Always
    env:
      - name: HOSTNAME_COMMAND
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.name}
      - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
        value: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_${HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
```

First HOSTNAME_COMMAND resolves successfully, so I see the pod's hostname.
I need to have the same for the second HOSTNAME_COMMAND, so I need to see something like this:

```
value: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_kafka-6b97669c5c-lhfp7:9094
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(ENV_NAME)` format inside other config, The details is here, [Using environment variables inside of your config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config).

Comment: ` command: ["bin/bash", "-c", "export"]
        args: ["INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_$(HOSTNAME_COMMAND):9094"] `
I added this, maybe I did it wrong, but not helped...

Comment: Re attache the whole .yaml file

Comment: `apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
....

    spec:
      hostname: kafka
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        image: wurstmeister/kafka
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        restartPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: HOSTNAME_COMMAND
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.name}
          - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
            value: $HOSTNAME_COMMAND
          - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
            value: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_${HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
        `

Comment: You can use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/). I think you have a mistake in the `yaml` file, that's why I'm asking for the whole file.